# good practice for cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, mathematical-statistics, sas, hierarchical-clustering

I want to find out what are the best practice in conducting a reliable cluster analysis:

1. Outliers: Is it necessary or not to remove the outliers in the variables to be used for cluster analysis?
2. Missing values in the variables to be used for cluster analysis: include cases with missing values?
3. Skewed data: do transformation to correct the sknewness?
4. Highly correlated variables to be used for cluster analysis: what can I do if most of the variables are highly correlated?
5. My data has 80K rows (cases). Shall I first use aceclus to prepare the data, and then use fastclus and produce 50 clusters, and then use cluster following fastclus. Will this do a better job than using fastclus or cluster alone?

can anyone give me some ideas what people usually do when conducting cluster analysis? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is aceclus, fastclus. Packages in SAS? If you don't explain what are these procedures or if they are found only in SAS, then you Q is not a statistical but a software-specific and is off-topic here then.

Comment: What people "usually" do ought to depend on the circumstances, the nature of the data, and the ensuing decisions that will be made.  That suggests this question may be too broad to be answerable on this site.  Since you seem to have data, why don't you narrow your question to focus on the particular problem you have?

Comment: You can also ask a series of questions, 1 after another, as you understand more. You can link back to your previous questions for context if appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Know your data and know your objectives.

1. Outiers: 
   If your data has outliers, a cluster algorithm will put them in separate small clusters and all the rest in one or a few big ones. 
   If you are doing fraud analysis, do so. You are interested in the outliers.
   If you are optimising sales in retail, exclude your outliers. They are not going to bring much about.
2. Missing values:
   Why are they missing? Is that related to what your study? Non answered questions on a survey might tell a lot about your subjects. If not, then you can probably impute them (`proc impute`).
3. I have little to say about skewness, but maybe a logarithmic transformation makes sense to reduce it.
4. Highly correlated variable can appear if you have multiple measurements estimating the same hidden aspect of reality. That aspect will then dominate your results and other aspects will be neglected. Principle component analysis can reduce that.
5. I have no opinion on that.